# Replacement of pager and previous/next class of bootstrap 3 in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used to use `pager` class in Bootstrap 3 to implement pagination.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
select {
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
}
</style>

<ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous disabled">
        <a>&larr; Newer</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span>
            Page:
            <select name="pagelist" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            of 3
        </span>
    </li>

    <li class="next">
        <a>Older &rarr;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

These days I upgrade to Bootstrap 4 and find [`pager` is dropped](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#pagination). I find many examples in [Bootstrap 4 Pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/), so I change my code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
select {
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
}
</style>

<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item previous disabled">
        <a class="page-link">&larr; Newer</a>
    </li>

    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link">Page:
            <select name="pagelist" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            of 3
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="page-item next" style="float:right">
        <a class="page-link">Older &rarr;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, `previous` and `next` class are dropped too and I didn't find examples in that official tutorial. I tried to add `float` style to them, but it doesn't work.

I find a similar issue in https://github.com/e107inc/e107/issues/2962, but it seems it changes to `<div>` instead. Is there a way to use `pagination` class in Bootstrap 4 to implement what I do in Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

------ Update  ----

Simply changing `justify-content-center` to `justify-content-between` will do the trick.

-------Original Answer ----------

Though I don't find a direct solution, I use an alternative described in https://github.com/e107inc/e107/issues/2962 with [Bootstrap 4 Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) and [Bootstrap 4 Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
select {
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
}
</style>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="pager-button btn btn-outline-primary disabled">
        <a>&larr; Newer</a>
    </div>

    <div class="pager-button btn btn-outline-primary">
        <a>Page:
            <select name="pagelist" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            of 3
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="pager-button btn btn-outline-primary">
        <a>Older &rarr;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Feel free to remove `pager-button` class.

And the button has many styles, it's convinient to choose among them.